# Limit of determinant/norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that 
$$\lim_{H\to0} \frac{|\det(H)|}{|H|}=0$$ where H is a 2x2 Matrix. I tried using the formulas:
$$\lim_{H\to0} \frac{ad-bc}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}}=0$$ but I am not sure if it is the right method. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is $\left|H\right|$? I know that as a way to write the determinant, which would not make sense here...

Comment: Looks like $|H|$ is Frobenius norm of $H$ to me, given the way it is used.

Comment: Yeah, Frobenius makes sense. Now, what is $H\to 0$? The limit must be defined with respect to a norm - also Frobenius?

Comment: $$for |H|=\sqrt{\sum_{i}\sum_{j} a_{ij}^2}$$ with a the Matrix entries

Answer (score 1):

Just try to square the whole expression. The degree in the numerator will be higher than in the denominator.

Comment: That alone does not prove the limit is $0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that each of $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|$ is bounded above by $\|H\|.$ Thus the expression is no more than

$$\frac{2\|H\|^2}{\|H\|} = 2\|H\| \to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$|ad-bc| \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}. \sqrt{d^2+c^2} $$
Thus

$$\frac{|ad-bc|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}} \leq \sqrt{d^2+c^2}$$

your limit is equivalent to a,b,c,d go to 0, in particular d,c go to 0, thus your limit is equals to 0.

Comment: For inequalty use Cauchy-Schwarz .